# Monkey-patching methods only inside my own code (by automatically using refinements?)

Tags: ruby, refinements

In my Ruby (on Rails) project, I’d like to forbid or restrict the usage of some methods provided by the standard library. Examples: I’d like to forbid calling `Float#to_d` because I had a rounding error when someone was using that method on a Float literal. I’d like to restrict `String#to_d` to work only with fully valid Strings because I had some bug resulting from `'string'.to_d` returning `0.0`.

Monkey-patching / overriding these methods globally is of course a bad idea. It may break some dependency.

Adding a linter rule that scans the code to not have calls to any `#to_d` method has the problem that it falsely restricts calling legit methods like `Integer#to_d`. Of course, all the legit methods could be added to the corresponding classes under a different name. But this requires adding a lot of boilerplace (for the methods) and changing all calls of these methods.

I also considered using refinements. This would be similar to monkey-patching, but apply only to scopes where the refinement is used. However, having to add `using` statements to every file would be ugly and error-prone. Is it possible to activate a refinement automatically for every file in my project, but not for dependencies?

Comment: Just to be sure, you think even just something like `using StrictFP`  is too much boilerplate?

Comment: Refinements are really resistant to metaprogramming, they just don't work unless you write 'using' in the lexical scope (same file) as the original class definition. I don't know a better way to do this besides getting 100% test coverage and making your tests fail if the methods get called

Comment: @maxpleaner Can you be more specific about what you mean by "really resistant"? Will I run into problems if both the file that defines and the file that uses the metaprogramming are in scope of the `using` statement?

Comment: You basically can't call `using` in any metaprogramming, that's the issue. First of all you can't call it inside of any method.  Second, you can only use `using` on `self.` Third, even if you do something like `MyClass.class_exec { using SomePatch }`  the refinement won't actually be active in any other file.

Comment: @maxpleaner Ah ok, I misunderstood your previous comment.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Yes, my application contains over 500 Ruby files. Around 100 of them use methods that I potentially want to restrict. That’s a large number of lines to add. It would be problematic if I forget to add the `using` statement after starting to use e.g. `String#to_d` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkeypatch if you're careful about it. I tried to implement it, see if it works. Obviously, you'll take a large performance hit, so I wouldn't recommend it in production :P One could speed it up quite a bit by memoising the tested locations instead of going up the directory tree each time the method is called.

The idea is to move the original method out of the way if defined on the class, then substitute a method that will check whether or not you're calling from your code. I'm using the directory that contains `.git` directory as your project directory; if you have a `vendor` directory directly in your project directory, it is exempt, as is everything outside the project directory. If you are in a location that is exempt, just pass things along to either the saved old method or up the inheritance chain; if not, scream foul.

```
require 'pathname'

PROJECT_CODE = Pathname.new(__dir__).ascend.find { |loc| (loc / '.git').directory? }
VENDOR_CODE = PROJECT_CODE / 'vendor'

class ForbiddenMethodError < StandardError; end

def forbid_method(klass, meth, &block)
  case
  when klass.instance_methods(false).include?(meth)
    old_meth = :"forbid_method_old_#{meth}"
    klass.alias_method old_meth, meth
  when klass.respond_to?(meth)
    old_meth = nil
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "No such method: #{klass}##{meth}"
  end

  klass.define_method(meth) do |*args|
    if !block || instance_exec(*args, &block)
      caller_loc = Pathname.new(caller_locations.first.path).expand_path
      caller_loc.ascend do |ancestor|
        case ancestor
        when PROJECT_CODE
          raise ForbiddenMethodError, "#{klass}##{meth}", caller[2..]
        when VENDOR_CODE
          break
        end
      end
    end

    if old_meth
      send(old_meth, *args)
    else
      super(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

With this, you can make `Float#to_d` and (conditionally) `String#to_d` fail in project code:

```
require 'bigdecimal/util'
forbid_method(Float, :to_d)
forbid_method(String, :to_d) { !BigDecimal(self) rescue true }
```

If you pass a block, the function is only forbidden if the block condition is truthy. (The block will get passed all the method's arguments, and will execute with the forbidden method's receiver as `self`.)